# how to use html php special chars function in a form input?

Tags: cakephp, summernote

I have input form in a add.ctp

```
echo $this->Form->input('Postdetail.0.post_text', array('label' => 'متن ', 'id' => 'editkoniman'));
```

And i want the result of that warped in a htmlspecialchars function befor saving in a database because i use summernote bootstrap WYSIWYG editor in a modal box

Comment: Spock, don't do that! Instead save raw, and encode for output if necessary.

Comment: please leave a link for raw saving instruction, tanks

Comment: Whats there to instruct? just call save(). nothing else required. h() should be used in the view layer for outputting the content. not before that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me explain how to implement your requirement.

As like @mark said, just save the data in your controller

```
$this->{YourModel}->save($this->request->data);
```

Here `$this->request->data` contains your post data.

To display the `post_text` in your view just put the strings in `h()` function to escape html characters

```
h($yourvariable['ModelName']['post_text'])
```